# getting blank screen in Ubuntu 16.04 after login account

Tags: 16.04

I am using 16.04 Ubuntu. After login , I am getting blank screen, nothing is displayed, how to fix the problem.

Comment: This is a very general description for a problem that can have many different reasons. Please add as much detail to your question (you can [edit] it) as possible, e.g. what graphics hardware and drivers you use, did it work before or is this a fresh installation, did you recently change anything, settings, updates, etc?

Comment: Graphics-intel. Before ubantu I was using Windows 10, I am using ubantu from 7 days.  Today I restarted laptop from that time I am getting blank screen and just after 1 min it changes to blue.

Comment: It is spelled Ubuntu. U B U N T U. No single A in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then typing the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Please tell me what the output of this is and if it works

Comment: When should I press  ctrl+alt+f1 - before login or after login

Comment: It works and solve  my problem

Comment: @RajanKumar if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey round check button on its left. That way you mark your question as solved and give the answerer a few reputation points as a reward. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.